# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with numpy in cygwin

Tags: python, bash, numpy, matplotlib, cygwin

A few days ago while running numpy in cygwin I got this:

```
$ python3.8
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.random.random(20)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

The problem actually arose with a different numpy method, but this is a simpler instance of the same problem. Note that *the message is printed out by python* before exiting back to bash.

I managed to get it working by downgrading (inside a python virtual environment) **numpy** from version **1.21.4** to **1.20.3** and thought that was it.

Afterwards while running **matplotlib**, the method `figure.tight_layout()` failed and printed out the same `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`message in exactly the same way. I ran it with the `faulthandler` enabled and got this:

```
[...]
  File "/home/user/.pyvenv8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 43 in _amin
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 633 in get_extents
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 2089 in _update_label_position
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1105 in get_tightbbox
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 4619 in get_tightbbox
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 82 in _auto_adjust_subplotpars
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 320 in get_tight_layout_figure
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 3197 in tight_layout
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

It's apparently **numpy** again that caused the issue (Unless your better opninion).
Line 43 is the one that caused the issue according to the output

```
41  def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
42            initial=_NoValue, where=True):
43      return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
```

The following is another instance of the same issue, which points at numpy too.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 898 in fillFormat
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 894 in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 375 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 434 in _get_format_function
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 501 in _array2string
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 475 in wrapper
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 698 in array2string
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/arrayprint.py", line 1447 in _array_repr_implementation
```

And the error is traced back to:

```
896      def fillFormat(self, data):
897          # only the finite values are used to compute the number of digits
898          finite_vals = data[isfinite(data)]
```

Perhaps it is worth it to mention that I installed cygwin in exactly the same way in a different system (hp laptop [ZBook]) and everything just worked as expected and here I installed it in a ThinkPad (L15).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have  you tried to used python3.8 instead of python3 ? What is the output of `alternatives --display python3` ?

Comment: Maybe you can try the version of python from `python.org`, to see if it has the same problem.

Comment: @matzeri I’m sorry for my clumsiness, I forgot to clarify that python3 is actually aliased to python3.8, which in turn is within the cygwin files, so I don’t think that’s the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

On Cygwin 64 bit with

```
$ cygcheck -c python38 python38-numpy
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
python38             3.8.12-1       OK
python38-numpy       1.21.4-1       OK
```

your code works with a minor change

```
$ python3.8
Python 3.8.12 (default, Nov 23 2021, 20:18:25)
[GCC 11.2.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.random(20)
array([0.23053439, 0.62286076, 0.26295642, 0.40334288, 0.93366687,
       0.3700992 , 0.32926097, 0.25258836, 0.66502201, 0.00174633,
       0.6095529 , 0.19894018, 0.08591355, 0.92748402, 0.24237812,
       0.24362117, 0.04083416, 0.64795586, 0.74237742, 0.92671093])
```

If this is not the result than or you have an installation issue or something else is interfering with the two packages.

The proper place for support is the cygwin mailing list
https://cygwin.com/problems.html

> Run cygcheck -s -v -r > cygcheck.out and include that file as an
> attachment in your report. Please do not compress or otherwise encode
> the output. Just attach it as a straight text file so that it can be
> easily viewed.

Comment: I will submit as you suggest the issue for support to cygwin. Thank you @matzeri for you help.